# Change django language code from URL pattern

Tags: python, django, web

I have this languages code setup on my Django application.

```
LANGUAGES = [
   ('en', _('English (US)')),
   ('de', _('Deutsch')),
   ('fr',_('Français')),
   ('ja',_('日本語')),# -> JP
   ('ko',_('한국어')),# -> KR
]
```

And on the url patterns i have the following setup:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False
)
```

So my application has the languages folder prefixed on the URLs.

But i need the languages ja and ko to work from other prefixes, jp and kr, respectively.

I tried using a middleware to override the request.path_info and the site responds on the required urls but it builds the internal links on the bad urls.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't possible, django consume this properties according to the HTML rules.
You can see all the allowed langs codes here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32619537)